# making a left sidebar right compatible

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am trying to convert a left sidebar to be compatible on the right.
I tried a few things but nothing worked for me.
basically, I need a right-to-left direction, because all my site is from right-to-left.
anyone can help me? here is my code (to be honest it is not really mine):
Thank you very much

```css
/*===== GOOGLE FONTS =====*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");

/*===== VARIABLES CSS =====*/
:root{
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --nav-width: 68px;

  /*===== Colors =====*/
  --first-color: #4723D9;
  --first-color-light: #AFA5D9;
  --white-color: #F7F6FB;
  
  /*===== Font and typography =====*/
  --body-font: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  
  /*===== z index =====*/
  --z-fixed: 100;
}

/*===== BASE =====*/
*,::before,::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  position: relative;
  margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  transition: .5s;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*===== HEADER =====*/
.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: var(--white-color);
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  transition: .5s;
}

.header__toggle{
  color: var(--first-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__img{
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header__img img{
  width: 40px;
}

/*===== NAV =====*/
.l-navbar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -30%;
  width: var(--nav-width);
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
}

.nav{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav__logo, .nav__link{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem;
}

.nav__logo{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.nav__logo-icon{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.nav__logo-name{
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.nav__link{
  position: relative;
  color: var(--first-color-light);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: .3s;
}

.nav__link:hover{
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.nav__icon{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

/*Show navbar movil*/
.show{
  left: 0;
}

/*Add padding body movil*/
.body-pd{
  padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 1rem);
}

/*Active links*/
.active{
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.active::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--white-color);
}

/* ===== MEDIA QUERIES=====*/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
  body{
    margin: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem) 0 0 0;
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem);
  }

  .header{
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem);
    padding: 0 2rem 0 calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem);
  }

  .header__img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }

  .header__img img{
    width: 45px;
  }

  .l-navbar{
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  }
  
  /*Show navbar desktop*/
  .show{
    width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px);
  }

  /*Add padding body desktop*/
  .body-pd{
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 188px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- ===== BOX ICONS ===== -->
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@2.0.5/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <!-- ===== CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">

    <title>Sidebar menu responsive</title>
</head>

<body id="body-pd">
    <header class="header" id="header">
        <div class="header__toggle">
            <i class='bx bx-menu' id="header-toggle"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="header__img">
            <img src="assets/img/perfil.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
        <nav class="nav">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="nav__logo">
                    <i class='bx bx-layer nav__logo-icon'></i>
                    <span class="nav__logo-name">Bedimcode</span>
                </a>

                <div class="nav__list">
                    <a href="#" class="nav__link active">
                        <i class='bx bx-grid-alt nav__icon'></i>
                        <span class="nav__name">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                        <i class='bx bx-user nav__icon'></i>
                        <span class="nav__name">Users</span>
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                        <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav__icon'></i>
                        <span class="nav__name">Messages</span>
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                        <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav__icon'></i>
                        <span class="nav__name">Favorites</span>
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                        <i class='bx bx-folder nav__icon'></i>
                        <span class="nav__name">Data</span>
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                        <i class='bx bx-bar-chart-alt-2 nav__icon'></i>
                        <span class="nav__name">Analytics</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                <i class='bx bx-log-out nav__icon'></i>
                <span class="nav__name">Log Out</span>
            </a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <h1>Components</h1>
    <!--===== MAIN JS =====-->
    <script>
        /*===== SHOW NAVBAR  =====*/
        const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
            const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
                nav = document.getElementById(navId),
                bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
                headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId)

            // Validate that all variables exist
            if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
                toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    // show navbar
                    nav.classList.toggle('show')
                    // change icon
                    toggle.classList.toggle('bx-x')
                    // add padding to body
                    bodypd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
                    // add padding to header
                    headerpd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
                })
            }
        }

        showNavbar('header-toggle', 'nav-bar', 'body-pd', 'header')

        /*===== LINK ACTIVE  =====*/
        const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

        function colorLink() {
            if (linkColor) {
                linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
                this.classList.add('active')
            }
        }
        linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: By compatible, what do you mean? Do you want the sidebar on the right side instead of left?

Comment: You need to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and specify which elements are being troublesome. If you want someone to look through hundreds of lines of code, they probably won't do it for free

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal yes, I want the sidebar on the right instead of the left